# Controller as syntax Angularjs not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Sorry, I'm new to AngularJs. I made an application that receives data from the service, and displays it in main.html. Before that, I used $scope. And everything worked. But with as controller syntax, the application does not work.

**main.html:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in main.newItems">
 <img src="{{item.min_img}}">
 <div>{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var shopApp = angular.module("shopApp",["ngRoute"]);

shopApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/main',{
                templateUrl:'/main.html',
                controller:"mainCtrl",
                controllerAs:"main"});
}]);

shopApp.controller("mainCtrl",function(newItemsFactory){
    this.newItems=newItemsFactory.getNewItems().then(function success(response) {
        this.newItems=response.data;
    });
});

shopApp.factory('newItemsFactory',function($http){
    return{
        getNewItems:function(){
            return $http({method: 'GET', url: 'newItems.json'});    
        }
    }
});
```

**newItems.json**

```
[
{"min_img:1.png",name:"first"},
{"min_img:2.png",name:"second"},,
{"min_img:3.png",name:"third"},
]
```

Sorry for my bad Engish and Thank.

Comment: `this.newItems=response.data;` I do believe in this case the `this` is in reference to the function it's inside. When using controller as it's best to define a variable at the top of the controller like `var main = this;` then you can change it to `main.newItems = blah blah`

Comment: try use `var vm = this` instead of `this` in controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a wrong assignment and wrong `this` in your controller.
The common pattern is to capture `this` in a variable `vm`:

```
shopApp.controller("mainCtrl",function(newItemsFactory){
  var vm = this;
  newItemsFactory.getNewItems().then(function success(response) {
    vm.newItems = response.data;
  });
});
```